# how to add ng click handler dynamically in jquery smart wizard for next button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm just trying to add ng-click handler to a button.
How can i do this? I tried the below code but it's not
working,any help appreciated.

```
btNext = $('<a>' + options.labelNext + '</a>').attr("href", "").addClass("buttonNext");
$('.buttonNext').attr('ng-click', 'LoadSecondDivDetails()');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because **AngularJS** compiles your code once.

In order for `ng-click` to work, you need to tell it to compile again.

Use `$compile` provider to tell **AngularJS** to recompile your portion of html.

In your case:

```
btNext = $compile('<a ng-click="your_action()"></a>')($scope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Mixing angularJS and jquery is not recommended. AngularJS is already handling DOM elements and you can really end up with some unwanted behavior. I would keep the entire wizard in an angularJS format using ngShow/ngHide to create the wizard form(s) for the wizard. Then you can just scope a variable to ng-show

```
 ng-show="currentPage == 1"
```

and then have submit run a function that changes to the next section of the wizard.

```
ng-submit="loadNext(2)"
```

and you have a function that handles all of this. Something like

```
$scope.loadNext = function () {
   $scope.currentPage += 1;
};

$scope.goBack = function () { //this can be your back button
    $scope.currentPage -= 1;
};
```